# Авторизация на php

Tags: php, авторизация

Вроде проблемы с кодировкой, с session_start решил. Но тут другие проблемки
Подскажите, что не так. Вот, что на странице:

```
<?php 
                if(isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"])) { 
                    include ("auth/members.php");
                }
                else {
                    include ("auth/login.php");
                    include ("form.php");
                }
```

members.php

```
<?php
print("<b>".$_SESSION["login"]."</b>! Welcome<br>\n");
print("<a href=\"auth/logout.php"."\">Exit</a>");
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
valid($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"]);

if( !($row = checkPass($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"])) ) {
    $messages[]='Wrong login or password';

}
else {  
cleanMemberSession($row['name'], $row['pass']);
}
}
?>
```

И form.php В общем там форма для отправки данных с такими параметрами

```
<form style="margin: 240px 0" action="users.php" method="post"><input type='submit' name='log_in' value="Войти">
```

</form>

Авторизация работает отлично, только вот, после того, как нажимаешь авторизоваться, происходит вроде как перезагрузка страницы и формa для входа остается. Чтобы форма пропала нужно еще дополнительно перезагрузить страницу или еще раз войти с помощью формы. Как это исправить. Чтобы сразу после нажатия на "Войти" входило.

Comment: Прокомментируйте свой код, пожалуйста. Трудно читается. :)

Comment: В общем на странице, где требуется авторизация:
Если была установлена $_SESSION.. то выводим members.php, где пишем Имя пользователя, Добро пожаловать и кликабельное "Выйти".
Иначе, если не установлена подключаем login.php, которая получает login и password от формы и функции, которые вызываются в login.php проверяют не пусты ли логин и пароль, потом функция, которая проверяет по БД сходятся ли логин и пароль. Ну а потом записываются, если все успешно в $_SESSION['login'] и $_SESSION['pass'] и $_SESSION['loggedIn']. И на общей странице проверяется, была ли установлена $_SESSION['loggedIn'].

Comment: @js_cbs а можно, пожалуйста, код страницы `users.php`?

Comment: Это небольшая ошибка, там должна быть index.php. Но смысл не в этом. Любую страницу приходится дополнительно перезагружать

Comment: @js_cbs значит дайте `index.php`. Мне надо знать как обрабатывается запрос.

Comment: @js_cbs вы понимаете, что удалив атрибут `action` вы обрабатываете запрос там же, где проверяете наличие сессии? Я бы советовал вам обрабатывать запрос на другой странице.

Comment: А автоматический редирект после авторизации уже не в моде, не?

Comment: Когда решу текущую проблему покумекаю насчет Ваших замечаний. Меня интересует почему такая проблема возникает..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишу вкратце суть.

```
<form style="margin: 240px 0" action="login.php" method="post"><input type='submit' name='log_in' value="Войти">
```

В login.php вы должны вызвать session_start()?, проверить возвращаемые из формы данные и если все гуд, то присваиваете $_SESSION['loggedIn'] требуемое значение и сразу редиректите на index.php (или как там у вас первый приведенный скрипт обозван) с выходом из текущего скрипта login.php Как-то так

```
header('Location: '.$_REQUEST['URI']);
exit;
```

UPD: login.php НЕ НАДО подключать в index.php, он вызывается автоматом при нажатии submit, после обработки данных вы просто должны вернуть управление основному скрипту!

UPD2:

index.php

```
<?php 
     session_start();
     .... // Может еще что-то 
     if(isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"])) { 
        include ("auth/members.php");
     }
     else {
         //include ("auth/login.php"); удаляем из-за ненадобности
         include ("form.php");
     }
```

form.php

```
 <form style="margin: 240px 0" action="auth/login.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="URI" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" /><input type='submit' name='log_in' value="Войти"></form>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
        if(valid($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"]))
            $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = ????; // призваиваем то, что надо
    }
    header('Location: '.$_REQUEST['URI']);
    exit;
```

Comment: Переходит на index.php, НО: как я уже говорил, $_SESSION['loggedIn'] получается, что сбивается, ну или если смотреть по коду - !isset. Следовательно снова загружается форма.
session_start запускается, думаю, Вы убедились, если смотрели скриншоты. Тогда я не понимаю в чем дело 8(
Также, если вместо редиректа вывести echo $_SESSION['loggedIn'] то он выводится, следовательно, устанавливается

Comment: Вы не стартуете сессию, поэтому данные и теряются! Добавьте в index.php после header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); эту злосчастную :)
session_start();

Также ваш стиль построения страницы сайта никуда не годен! Разве что для обучения базовым навыкам! Хороший стиль предполагает отделение HTML от основного скрипта вынесением его в файлы-шаблоны. Запомните это на будущее, если хотите писать сайты, это сэкономит вам кучу нервов.

Comment: Вооот, теперь сохраняется. НО: мне нужно наладить редирект нормальный, чтобы он на предыдущую ворачивался, а не только на главную

Черт не понимаю что за дела. Сейчас только сессия сохранялась, и уже нет.

Comment: Ну так работает или нет не понял что-то? Редирект нормальный я вам уже описал:
В форме скрытое поле с именем типа 'URI' 

    ('<input type="hidden" name="URI" value="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" />'), 

в login.php

     header("Location: ".$_POST['URI']);
     exit;

Comment: Как только поменял заработало, но потом перестало. 
Поменял на то что Вы выше написали:
The requested URL /tsaryov/auth/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].' was not found on this server.
После "Войти"

Comment: Вы это добавили в form.php???

    <input type="hidden" name="URI" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />

Второе: вы отличаете относительные пути от абсолютных? Я же не знаю конкретно, как у вас на сайте размещены файлы. header("Location: index.php") и header("Location: /index.php") не всегда одно и тоже (первый относительно текущего выполняемого скрипта, второй от корня сайта). Все я спать, изучайте PHP, вот вам статейка по простенькой авторизации с помощью сессий почитать http://blog.ox2.ru/php/avtorizaciya-i-rabota-sessii/, удачи.

Comment: Сейчас работает редирект просто отлично, НО: Вот смотрите, в index.php запускаю сессию и нарочно пишу $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false.
А в файле login.php пишу echo $_SESSION['loggedIn']. И как Вы думаете что происходит? А ничего не происходит. После этих переходов от index.php к login.php и наоборот, сессия пропадает и echo не выводит "0". Почему???

Comment: Ну не знаю тогда. Попробуйте вывести идентификатор сессии после ее запуска и посмотрите, совпадает ли он до и после редиректа. Проверьте также состояние session.use_trans_sid в php.ini. Как вариант, можно еще попробовать в ручную добавлять SID в URL http://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.idpassing.php Передача сессии при php-редиректе и отключенных куках в браузере клиента - http://www.webengineer.pro/php-scripts/11-redirekt-sredstvami-php

Comment: Возможно нашел причину, попробуйте вызывать http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-write-close.php после установки переменных сессии и перед редиректом.

Answer (score 0):

Вчера сбивалась сессия. У меня session_start() было только в index.php. Добавил еще session_start() в login.php непосредственно перед занесением логина, пароля в сессионные переменные. Тогда сессия сохранялась и было всё прекрасно. Лег спать счастливым. Сегодня же с утра сессия опять сбивается 8(

UPD: А нет :). Я балбес просто логин и пароль неправильные ввожу. Все работает. Но факт остается фактом - сессию стартовать нужно и на login.php и на index.php.. Странно

Огромнейшее спасибо всем, кто помогал мне в данном вопросе, в особенности MDJHD'у.

Comment: И в этом была причина?? Я перерыл пол мануала по сессиям, чтобы понять, почему у вас не работает так как надо, а вы всего-лишь по невнимательности забыли добавить session_start()!!! :)))

Comment: Сильно пресильно извиняюсь :) Вчера с обеда до ночи просидел с "авторизацией". Голова под вечер кипела..

Comment: @MDJHD ему ранее говорили стартовать сессию на каждой странице, а он всё равно забыл. XD

Comment: Никто этого не говорил