# Работа с куками и сессиями

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Добрый день, я что-то не могу найти простой рабочий пример демонстрации работы с куками и сессией.

Ну самые элементарные примеры брал, где есть логин и пароль, и надо со всеми страницами сайта сперва связать проверку, является пользователь зарегистрированным - если да, то показываем информацию, если нет - выводим окно авторизации. И ещё прикол с ВЫХОДом. Во многих примерах-вроде и работает, но браузер сохраняет значения. Т.е. потом придёт кто-то, введёт имя, а пароль и сам подставится. Как-то не серьёзно.

- Подскажите, как это реализовать?
- Как при нажатии на "Выход" полностью всё подчистить?

Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

[работы с куками и сессией](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl8_1.php)

[Работа с файлами сессий и cookies](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=28&id=427)

[На Хэшкоде, в ответах есть пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/326632/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php)

> Во многих примерах-вроде и работает, но браузер сохраняет значения. Т.е. потом прийдёт кто-то- введётимя, а пароль и сам подставится. Как-то не серъёзно.

Браузер отдельно спрашивает у пользователя, нужно ли сохранять пароль, и при положительном ответе он его сохранит куда-то к себе и сессии и куки здесь не причем.

Comment: насчёт последнего: можно снабдить поле атрибутом autocomplete